# How do i install JoggApp/laravel-google-translate using composer?

Tags: laravel

I'm new to laravel and i'm completely stuck here. Im trying to install it using this command `composer require joggapp/laravel-google-translate`.

Im however getting this error which i do not know how to solve:

Im not sure whether the problem is with my composer version or what the real problem is.

```
 Problem 1
    - google/cloud-core[v1.14.0, ..., v1.37.1] require guzzlehttp/guzzle ^5.3|^6.0 -> found guzzlehttp/guzzle[5.3.0, ..., 5.3.x-dev, 6.0.0, ..., 6.5.x-dev] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^7.0.1).
    - google/cloud-core[v1.38.0, ..., v1.42.2] require guzzlehttp/psr7 ^1.2 -> found guzzlehttp/psr7[1.2.0, ..., 1.x-dev] but the package is fixed to 2.0.0 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.
    - joggapp/laravel-google-translate v7.0.0 requires google/cloud-translate ^1.2 -> satisfiable by google/cloud-translate[v1.2.0, ..., v1.10.1].
    - google/cloud-translate[v1.9.0, ..., v1.10.1] require google/cloud-core ^1.39 -> satisfiable by google/cloud-core[v1.39.0, ..., v1.42.2].
    - google/cloud-translate[v1.7.0, ..., v1.8.1] require google/cloud-core ^1.35 -> satisfiable by google/cloud-core[v1.35.0, ..., v1.42.2].
    - google/cloud-translate[v1.4.0, ..., v1.6.0] require google/cloud-core ^1.32 -> satisfiable by google/cloud-core[v1.32.0, ..., v1.42.2].
    - google/cloud-translate v1.3.0 requires google/cloud-core ^1.31 -> satisfiable by google/cloud-core[v1.31.0, ..., v1.42.2].
    - google/cloud-translate v1.2.9 requires google/cloud-core ^1.28 -> satisfiable by google/cloud-core[v1.28.0, ..., v1.42.2].
    - google/cloud-translate v1.2.8 requires google/cloud-core ^1.26 -> satisfiable by google/cloud-core[v1.26.0, ..., v1.42.2].
    - google/cloud-translate[v1.2.5, ..., v1.2.7] require google/cloud-core ^1.23 -> satisfiable by google/cloud-core[v1.23.0, ..., v1.42.2].
    - google/cloud-translate[v1.2.0, ..., v1.2.4] require google/cloud-core ^1.14 -> satisfiable by google/cloud-core[v1.14.0, ..., v1.42.2].
    - Root composer.json requires joggapp/laravel-google-translate ^7.0 -> satisfiable by joggapp/laravel-google-translate[v7.0.0].
```

this is my composer.json file:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.3|^8.0",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0.1",
        "laravel/framework": "^8.54",
        "laravel/sanctum": "^2.11",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.5",
        "laravel/ui": "^3.3"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "facade/ignition": "^2.5",
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "laravel/sail": "^1.0.1",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.2",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^5.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.3.3"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-assets --ansi"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

I will highly appreciate any assistance

Answer (score 1):

The error says you don't have the mongoDB extension installed for PHP.

And the package "jenssegers/mongodb" requires MongoDB extension.

You can follow the instructions [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/php/). and then try to `composer require joggapp/laravel-google-translate` and it should work.

Comment: i have mongodb installed and working perfectly on my machine but im still stuck here

Comment: MongoDB is running thats good.
But MongoDB PHP Driver and extensions are required PHP to communicate with your MongDB server.
PLease view this [link](https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/php/)

Comment: i have all that coz ive been reading and writing from mongo.  check my error message. i gues the problem is with versions but i dont know how to solve them